# I am unable to read the following json file. I have read json files that only contain one object but not as multiple json objects in Java using gson

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, arraylist

```
{
  "billingInformation": {
    "taxes": {
      "gst": 2.5,
      "hst": 7.8
    },
    "billTo": {
      "name" : "Mike",
      "address" : "123, Lake Shore Drive, California",
      "phoneNumber" : "601 855 1249"
    },
    "salesAgent": {
      "name" : "Charlotte Thompson",
      "agentCode" : 44551
    },
    "items": {
      "item": [
        {
          "hsnCode": "5112",
          "description": "TV Set",
          "originCountry": "US",
          "quantity": 1,
          "unitPrice": 150.00
        }
      ],
      "currency": "USD"
    }
  }
}
```

For now I just removed billingInformation and then have proceeded with the code as follows:

```
   Reader reader = new BufferedReader(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(bill)));
    JsonObject obj = JsonParser.parseReader(reader).getAsJsonObject();

    Taxes taxes = new Taxes();
    taxes.setGST(obj.getAsJsonObject("taxes").get("gst").getAsDouble());
    taxes.setHST(obj.getAsJsonObject("taxes").get("hst").getAsDouble());
```

But since billingInformation is a part of the json objects, I want to be able to traverse through it and to set the above-mentioned information in their respective objects. For ex: Billing Information will be set in the billing information object, items in the items object and so on, so that I can process that information further according to my use case.

Comment: "since billingInformation is a part of the json array" - I don't see it being part of any array. It seems "billingInformation" is the only property of the top level element and everything else is nested in it. So if you need to get "taxes" you now first need to get "billingInformation". Btw, I'm not a Gson user but I'm pretty sure it also supports direct mapping to proper pojos. Is there any reason for not using that feature and instead retrieve and cast individual properties yourself?

Comment: I apologise for framing the question in a wrong way and thank you for correcting me. I did in-fact tried to use direct mapping but it always resulted in null values

Answer (score 1):

I found two mistakes in your json file:

```
Incorrect: "phoneNumber" : 601 855 1249 
Correct: "phoneNumber" : "601 855 1249"

Incorrect: "name" : "Charlotte Thompson,
Correct: "name" : "Charlotte Thompson",
```

After validation of your json file, get the data by hierarchy as below:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(bill)));
JsonObject obj = JsonParser.parseReader(reader).getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println(obj);
JsonObject obj2 = obj.getAsJsonObject("billingInformation");
System.out.println(obj2);
Taxes taxes = new Taxes();
taxes.setGST(obj2.getAsJsonObject("taxes").get("gst").getAsDouble());
taxes.setHST(obj2.getAsJsonObject("taxes").get("hst").getAsDouble());
```

**Update 2023-1-27**

To iterate through the items list, firstly, create the item class.

```
class Item {
    private String hsnCode;
    private String description;
    private String originCountry;
    private String quantity;
    private String unitPrice;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

Secondly, continue with the above code:

```
//JsonObject obj2 = obj.getAsJsonObject("billingInformation");

// Get JsonElement
JsonElement yourJson = obj2.getAsJsonObject("items").get("item");
// Get Type of List<Item>
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType();
// Convert json to java list
List<Item> list = new Gson().fromJson(yourJson, listType);
// Iterate the list
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. Thanks! But I am unable to iterate through the items list.